# DataExporter calls load method twice on lazy DataTables

Tags: primefaces

I use lazy datatable in primefaces. When using data exporter, load method calls twice. Why does it call twice, anything wrong about this?

Comment: 2 calls with the same parameters? And what version do you use?

Comment: Not same parameter, firstly; first page query and then current page query is called. Primefaces version 6.1 is used.

Comment: What if ypu popukate it with 3 pages of data? What do the PF docs state?

Comment: It doesn't matter to have how many pages.For example, table has 10 pages and my current page is fifth. Load method call firstly with first page parameter, and then with fifth page parameter but export data is correct.

Comment: PF version do you use?

Comment: 6.1 PF version is used

Comment: Debug the PF source then... you can maybe see then waht they do. The source IS open